# Do ODEs have multiple general solutions or am I just missing something, and where does e keep coming from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the general solution to: $y' = 2xy$ 
My try:
$$[dy/dx = 2xy]dx/y$$
$$ydy = 2xdx$$
$$(\int y \,dy) = (\int 2x \,dx)$$
$$(1/2)y^2 + c_1 = 2x^2 + c_2$$
$$y = \sqrt{2x^2 + c}$$

So this is how I tried to solve this ODE. I used the same method for 2 others as well, but the solution manual says this: $y = ce^{x^2}$ \

I have no clue where and why e is/became part of the solution. This isn't the only problem where it occured, it's the same when I tried solving $xyy' = y-1$ and $xy' = (1-2x^2)tan(y)$. So I'm really confused.

Comment: That's because you should get $\frac{dy}{y}$ on the LHS

Comment: Your second step should be $dy/y$, not $y \, dy$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2xy\implies \frac{dy}{y}=2x dx\implies \log y-c_1=x^2-c_2\implies \log y=x^2+C\implies y=C'e^{x^2},$$ for some constant $C'=e^{c_1-c_2}$. Your mistake is in the first step, it should be $\frac{dy}{y}$ instead of $y dy$, since you divide by $y$ both sides.